# Xamarin CollectionView Updates Only Once After Updating Visual Studio and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with my project. I have been developing an application for several months and until yesterday everything was perfect. Today I had the unhealthy idea of updating visual studio to version 2022 and Xamarin.Forms to version 5.0.0.2291 and I realized now that all the CollectionViews in my code now update only once, after which to update it again I have to go to another page and then go back. Before the updates everything was working perfectly, so I guess the code is fine. Anyone know what may have happened? Thank you!

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  You haven't posted any code so we have no idea what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: When anything strange happens after an update, close VS, delete all bin and obj folders of your solution, then try again. Also, what version was XF before? I mean, was it 4.something, or was it one of the 5.something versions?

Comment: Other things to try. Manage Nugets / update other ones. VS Installer / Repair. Emulator / Factory Reset. Sounds like somewhere, “old” and “new” versions are mixing.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I found out that the new version of Xamarin.Forms is causing this problem. Before I had the 5.0.0.2244 version. Now I downgraded the package to that version and it now works... I'm wondering if anyone else is facing this problem.

Comment: have you searched for an existing bug report?

Comment: @Jason I only found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/671052/xamarin-forms-facing-weird-issues-after-installing.html) but i think that that's not correlated with my problem

Comment: But did you try the things I suggested? As I commented, sounds like you had a combination of old and new ..something. Sure, you go back to old, no problem. What we don’t know yet, is whether when you went forward to new version of XF, there is also something else you need to update or delete, to get to a good state. Want to eliminate that possibility, before concluding you have found a bug. Try a clean test: new folder, new solution, new XF, copy one of your collectionviews to it, work or break?

Comment: `Now I downgraded the package to that version and it now works...`  Thanks for your feedback. Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've tried everything you suggested doing but nothing. I created a new project from scratch following all your directions and downloading all the necessary packages that I used in my project (Xamarin.Forms, CommunityToolkit, etc ...) and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for doing that - definitely sounds like a bug. As Jessie suggests, Please make a public github with enough code to make the symptom happen.

Comment: Ok, i'll do that. Thanks for your support!!!